# "CommunicationException was unhandled by user code" when deploying web application to IIS

Tags: c#, mysql, silverlight, iis

I am new to IIS and Silverlight. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633789/Connecting-MySQL-From-SilverLight-With-Web-Service) to create a web application using Visual C#2010 and IIS 7.

The application is working perfectly when in visual studio using IIS express. When I deploy to Local IIS it shows this error:

> CommunicationException was unhandled by user code. An error occurred
>   while trying to make a request to URI
>   'http://localhost:55826/WebService1.asmx'
>
> This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain
>   way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is
>   unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the
>   service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows
>   SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by
>   using internal types in the web service proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception
>   for more details.

How can I deploy a web app based on MySQL to IIS without encountering this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the service available across domains when deployed. For this, you need to add a crossdomain.xml and a clientaccesspolicy.xml files to your web project. You can find more details here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(VS.95).aspx